# Once child thread completes its execution, will it resume executing main thread lines?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to create a child thread in a main thread as below,

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("In normal child thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            }
        });
        t1.start();
        System.out.println("main thread sleeping for 5 seconds : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("In main thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("exiting main thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}
```

In the above example, i have made main thread sleep for 5 seconds. So once the child thread completes printing its sysout statement, **I am expecting below lines to be executed twice,**

```
System.out.println("In main thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
System.out.println("exiting main thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

But when i execute the program, i see only once these lines are executed.

Please update me if my expectation is right? . **I am expecting main thread should execute these sysout statements twice.**

Comment: the child thread executes just what is inside its `run()` method

Comment: You have a heavy misunderstanding about what threads actually execute. A "child" thread executes whatever it is assigned to, which is per code inside `run()` in Java.

Comment: sorry i have edited the question. child thred will execute only whats mention in run().  what i am trying to understand is when the child thread completes execution, where will the control come to? ..

Comment: @vinodhy It will just terminate.

Comment: oh i see. i have also worked in c++. i some how remember that the lines were executing twice in c++. So i have raised this question.

Comment: @vinodhy maybe you used the [`fork()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) system call? But that is a completely different story...

Answer (score 0):

Here we're running two threads: the MainThread and the Child thread. When we invoke the start() method for the child thread(), the logic in the run() method is executed.
This child thread will die when its run method is executed.
The main thread continues with its execution of the remaining code.

Comment: What does *"The control will come to the main thread again."* mean?

Comment: I've kinda missed the point that you don't have enough reputation to comment. Please edit your answer to clarify that sentence. In the current state it's just confusing and the thought behind it probably wrong.

Comment: @bhavya.. Please explain more to help us understand. we can have a logical conclusion if you can please provide more information.